# Pause current sound when new sound is played css, html5 - audio, onclick

Tags: html, audio, onclick

I know there are threads about this but I was wondering what I change in this specific script to get the audio to pause when another is started. Thanks so much.

```
function playSound(el,soundfile) {
    if (el.mp3) {
        if(el.mp3.paused) el.mp3.play();
        else el.mp3.pause();
    } else {
        el.mp3 = new Audio(soundfile);
        el.mp3.play();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need somehow to remember last played sound object (keep reference to it) and pause it before you will play next sound. I made simple snippet, I used some sound that I found on web:

```js
var players = [{mp3: null}, {mp3: null}, {mp3: null}];

var currentAudio = null;

function playSound(el,soundfile) {
  if(currentAudio){
      currentAudio.pause();
    }

    if (el.mp3) {
        if(el.mp3.paused){
         currentAudio = el.mp3;
         el.mp3.play();
        } else {
         el.mp3.pause();
        }
    } else {
        el.mp3 = new Audio(soundfile);
        currentAudio = el.mp3;
        el.mp3.play();
    }
}

document.getElementById('player1Button').addEventListener('click', function(){
  playSound(players[0], 'http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3');
});

document.getElementById('player2Button').addEventListener('click', function(){
  playSound(players[1], 'https://www.nasa.gov/mp3/590189main_ringtone_131_launchNats.mp3');
});

document.getElementById('player3Button').addEventListener('click', function(){
  playSound(players[2], 'https://www.nasa.gov/mp3/581097main_STS-1_Dust-it-Off.mp3');
});

document.getElementById('stop').addEventListener('click', function(){
  if(currentAudio){
    currentAudio.pause();
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="player1Button">Play 1</button>
<button id="player2Button">Play 2</button>
<button id="player3Button">Play 3</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
```

Notice that when paused, sound will be resumed if played again from the last position it was paused, if you want it to stop, so pause and rewind so it will start playing again from the beginning, you would need to set `currentTime` of Audio object to 0 after you pause it: `currentAudio.currentTime = 0;`